# How to make a function update objects in Python?

Tags: python

I have been working on a Python program lately as a beginner dev
I am creating a function that will change an object called 'Score'.

Here is the full code of the function :

```
def Updating(solver : Solver, g: Goal, phase: Phase, a: int):
         solver_p = int(solver.get_score_at(g, phase))
         if a == 0:
            solver_p += 1

         return solver_p
```

My goal is to update the object "get_score_at" when calling it later in a Class.
By the present code, I am failing to update it correctly

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: `get_score_at` is a _method_, so it's unclear what you mean by "update" it. You probably need to update one of the _other_ attributes of the solver - right now you just return a new integer and change nothing about the objects the function received.

Comment: Can I update the "int" value of a method ?

Comment: Again it's unclear what you mean. Generally you change the _return value_ of a method by changing either its inputs or the state of the instance it's part of.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't a function that alters the state of an object not always be a class method?

So instead of getting the current score and add outside a 1 if there is an goal and try to write that back to solver, you should probably do the following like this.

Add a classmethod to your solver class like:

```py
def scores_goal(self):
    self.solver_p += 1
```

So if you then run solver.scores_goal() the value is increased by one internally.